# how to get data from html from and safe it as an object,dictionary,in python

Tags: python, html, flask

this is my code in my app

```
@app.route('/registration', methods=["POST","GET"])
def createuser():
    if request.method == "POST":
        status =request.form("rstatus")
        firstname = request.form("firstname")
        dob = request.form("dob")
        email = request.form("email")
        number = request.form("number")
        password = request.form("password")
        lastname = request.form("lastname")
        nickname = request.form("nickname")
        if status == "Customer":
            db = shelve.open("customer.db","c")
            db[nickname] =[firstname,dob,email,number,password,lastname]
            return render_template("Customer_Dashboard_Profile.HTML")
        elif status == "Staff":
            db = shelve.open("staff.db","c")
            db[nickname] =[firstname,dob,email,number,password,lastname]
            return render_template("Employee_Dashboard_Profile.HTML")
        else:
            print("ERROR")
```

and this is my html

```
<form action="/registration" class="form-signin" method="post">
                        <div class="form-label-group">
                            <select name="rstatus" id="rstatus" class="form-control">
                                <option value="Customer" selected>Customer</option>
                                <option value="Staff">Staff</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-label-group">
                            <input type="text" id="inputfirstname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="firstname" required>
                            <label for="inputFirstname">First Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-label-group">
                            <input type="date" id="inputDOB" class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Birth" name="dob"required>
                            <label for="inputDOB">Date of Birth</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-label-group">
                            <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" name="email" required autofocus>
                            <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-label-group">
                            <input type="number" id="inputphonenumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" name="number" required min="80000000" max="99999999">
                            <label for="inputphonenumber">Phone Number</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-label-group">
                            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" required>
                            <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-label-group">
                            <input type="password" id="inputconfirmPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirmpassword" required>
                            <label for="inputconfirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-label-group">
                            <input type="text" id="inputlastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname" required>
                            <label for="inputlastname">Last Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-label-group">
                            <input type="text" id="inputnickname" class="form-control" placeholder="Nickname" name="nickname" required>
                            <label for="inputnickname">Nickname</label>
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block text-uppercase" type="submit">Register</button><br>
                    </form>
```

when I click register it leads to an error page saying '404 Not Found'. I feel that the mistake has got something to do with request from or getting the status from the html page but I'm not sure what exactly is the problem

Comment: What does your webserver log when it produces the 404?

Comment: @noslenkwah how do I check that?

Comment: if you are running flask from the command line it will just print it out on the command line. It will show you what the browser was actually requesting. Not what you think it should be requesting.